# Laravel: Method Illuminate\Http\Response::assertInertia does not exist

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I'm trying make a simple test in my laravel/inertia project, but for the following test:

```
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    $portfolio = $this->createPortfolio();

    $response = $this->actingAs($portfolio->user)->get(route('portfolioCryptos.show'));

    $response->assertInertia(function (Assert $page) {
        $page->component('Portfolio.Show')
    });
```

I get the "BadMethodCallException" Method Illuminate\Http\Response::assertInertia does not exist.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the inertia-laravel version installed, updating to version ^0.4.0 solved the problem.